# Showing the last value from VLOOKUP

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

### Explanation

The way this spreadsheet should work is by checking if the `Status` value of the **last** corresponding `Data` value, is equal to "OK". If it is, then it'll show the corresponding value in `ValueIfOK`, in `Result`, if not, `ValueIfOK` will be blank, so it should show a blank value in `Result`.

I created [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FuB93lSnSScWmz8s2y3U7p6Se7q3aLUO-aM-kJJ9fik/edit) spreadsheet here to show what I meant above. It can be edited by anyone and doesn't need to login.

### Code

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
        VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet2!A2:D, 2, FALSE) = "OK", 
        VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet2!A2:D, 3, TRUE)
    )
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the values set

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
  VLOOKUP(
    A:A,
    SORT(Sheet2!A:C,ROW(Sheet2!A:A),0),3,0),
))
```

There is [the full explanation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l3oqJ2XB76lnIRsg45bxuTnjfA8JvvOaEDx-o-XoRqw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A:A, SORT(Sheet2!A:C, ROW(Sheet2!A:A), 4, 1), 3, 0)))
```